# How to convert EPS to PDF in Windows?

Tags: windows, pdf, eps

I have some EPS files and I need to convert them to PDF files in Windows. Google thus far points to me a lot of bad looking commercial software applications. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785436/ghostscript-command-line-parameters-to-convert-eps-to-pdf) on Stack Overflow describes how to convert EPS files to PDF using [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/). If you have any (specific) issues with that potential answer, come on back.

Answer (score 9):

When [MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/) is installed, you can use the command line

```
epstopdf input.eps --output output.pdf
```

On Windows 10 with Miktex 2.9.6500 64bit, the command is

```
epstopdf input.eps --outfile output.pdf
```

Comment: just wanted to point out that for me (Windows 10, MikTex 2.9) the `--output` option does not work. The working command is instead `epstopdf input.eps --outfile=output.pdf`

Comment: This is great: completely simple and does not require the cumbersome installing and usage of ghostscript.

Comment: Does MiKTeX requires GhostScript?

Comment: @Royi as far as I remember, it doesn't - but I have not tested recently, and I have Ghostscript installed on my machine for other reasons.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) to do this easily on command prompt.

1. Install Ghostscript, linked above
2. Open Command Prompt
3. Run `%programfiles%\gs\gs9.07\lib\ps2pdf.bat input.eps output.pdf`

   - Replace Ghostscript version as needed
   - You can also use the full document path for the input and output files
4. Done

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer sticking with GUI programs, use [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), which is [also available for Windows](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/). While it can open EPS documents, it cannot save to PDF directly, but using a free PDF printer like [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/). Could include some hassles to set the document size, though.

Comment: You can provide multiple solutions in a single answer.

Comment: Sure - but they've got nothing in common and are [_radically different_](http://meta.superuser.com/a/3430/102155) answers, and form two fully independent ways of achieving the problem. If I'd posted `ps2pdf` and calling ghostscript directly I'd totally agree with you, but these two solutions don't belong together.

Comment: Meh, going by what slhck wrote there I still feel these could have been combined, with a separator/HR if required. Anyway, that's all from me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of **online free converters**. I prefer to use them instead of installing software.

Take a look:
[onlineconverter.com](https://www.onlineconverter.com/eps-to-pdf)
Or
[Zamzar](https://www.zamzar.com/convert/eps-to-pdf/)

PS: You can do that with Adobe Illustrator, too.